# Canvas that should only be visible for local player is also visible for remote players

Tags: unity, unity-ui, unity-networking

I'm using Unity NetCode for Game Objects. I have a player Prefab, inside it I have a canvas as a child of my player Prefab (I don't know if it's the best approach), which contains inventory, status, etc. But when I instantiate more than one player, the canvas is also visualized by the other players. I wish to find a solution to solve this problem.

Comment: Delete the canvas if it is not the owner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three broad ways to solve this:

1. Keep the canvas inside the player prefab, but when instantiating a non-local player, destroy the canvas after spawning it.

   This is probably the simplest to implement from your current setup. Make a script that, on `Start()`, queries whether it belongs to the local player, and if not, destroys the object it's attached to. The downside is that you go to all the work of instantiating the canvas first, so to save that redundant work, it may be preferable to...
2. Remove the canvas from the player prefab. When instantiating a local player, instantiate their UI canvas separately and wire it up.

   This requires a bit more code, in case things in the canvas and in the prefab need to reference each other, but it's not too bad if you plan for it. If the wiring needed for local players is particularly complex, you may prefer to...
3. Make separate prefabs for local vs remote players, and spawn the appropriate asset depending on which kind of player it's being instantiated for.